# Cross-Compiling gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc, makefile, cross-compiling

I am following the instructions [here](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler) for cross-compiling GCC. I am on a mac. When I run this command from the gcc source folder: `./configure --target=i586-elf --prefix=/usr/local/cross --disable-nls --without-headers --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,fortran,java,objc,obj-c++,treelang` I get this error: `configure: error: GMP 4.1 and MPFR 2.2.1 or newer versions required by fortran`. When I change the command to this (I couln't compile GMP): `./configure --target=i586-elf --prefix=/usr/local/cross --disable-nls --without-headers --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,objc,obj-c++,treelang` I get this error:

```
The following requested languages could not be built: ada
Recognised languages are: c,ada,c++,fortran,java,objc,obj-c++,treelang
```

which doesn't make sense to me because it says ada is recognized. All other configurations of the enable-languages settings (and when the setting isn't changed and the default is used) give me this error:

```
/usr/local/cross/i586-elf/bin/ranlib ./libgcov.a
_error_not_here_yet - havent even thought about it - it may even work
make[1]: _error_not_here_yet: Command not found
make[1]: *** [treelang.all.cross] Error 127
make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
```

How can I cross compile GCC?

Comment: Try just enabling the languages you really want, for example `--enable-languages=c,c++`.

Comment: Yep. Depending what version you're trying to compile, Ada might have been deprecated and they just didn't update the help message.

Comment: +1 for the "_error_not_here_yet - havent even thought about it - it may even work" error message :-)

Comment: not working for go as well, 

"The following requested languages could not be built: go"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running `configure` from the gcc source tree? If so: don't do that. Follow the instructions (verbatim) in the page you linked to.

Look carefully and you'll notice that they're running the `configure` command from *outside* the gcc source tree.

If your platform is supported by it, the [crosstool script](http://www.kegel.com/crosstool/) (also linked from the bottom of your instructions page) is very helpful.

Edit: As potatoswatter points out in a comment, your installation is probably hosed at this point. Remove the whole tree and start from scratch. (It sounds like it will take too long, and you'll want to take a short cut, but it will be faster in the end if you just start from scratch now.)

Comment: Furthermore, running `configure` in there can corrupt an installation. At least, after I made that mistake I couldn't build it until I nuked and downloaded it all over again.

Comment: crosstool-ng is an actively maintained rewrite of crosstool
http://ymorin.is-a-geek.org/projects/crosstool

Comment: @Hasturkun - thanks for the link, I'll have to check that out next time I'm in need.

Comment: What GCC languages does crosstool-ng support?